# Converting fields inside a Serializer in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a project where one model, called `Request`, has two fields (`source`, `dest`) that contain two `id`s which are not known to the user. However, each one is connected to another model `User`, who let's say that they have one field, `username`, which *is* known to the user.

Now, I want to make a serializer that can take `username`s, and convert them into `id`s. (The opposite was simple to achieve, I just modified the `to_representation` method.) The problem is that when I send `{'source': 'john', 'dest': 'jim'}` the serializer does not take these data as valid. This was expected behavior, as it expected `id`s and got strings (`username`s). However, even when I overridden the `validate_source`, `validate_dest` and `validate` methods to actually check that the `username`s exist (instead of the `id`s), I am still getting errors that the serializer expected `id` but got string.

1. Are the `validate`, `validate_<field>` methods the wrong ones to override in this case?
2. Should I just convert the `username`s into `id`s inside my view?
3. is it pythonic and good practice, django-wise, to receive some fields from the user and change them inside the serializer (as I change `username` into `id`)?

Current Serializer:

```py
class RequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Request
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def validate_source(self, value):
        username = value.get('username')
        if username is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('`user` field is required ')
        return value

    def validate_dest(self, value):
        username = value.get('username')
        if username is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('`user` field is required ')
        return value

    def validate(self, attrs):
        self.validate_source(attrs['source'])
        self.validate_dest(attrs['dest'])
        return attrs
    
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        # do things
        pass
```

Please notice that this is not the whole functionality of my serializer. To convert from an `id` to a `username` I have to check the data of another Model, So I cannot use a SlugRelatedField.

Also, username is not the only item returned by the serializer. It also returns a `'class'` field, depending on which group the the user has joined. The user may join more than one group, and each user-group combination has its own `id`. In the same way, when deserializing the data, I will need to read (1) the username, and then (2) the group, and find the correct id.

Thank you.

Comment: Please share the current serializer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can work with a [**`SlugRelatedField`** <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield):

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    source = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=User.objects.all(),
        slug_field='username',
    )
    dest = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=User.objects.all(),
        slug_field='username',
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('source', 'dest')
```

This will return the `username` of the `source` and `dest` field of the model object, and in the opposite direction will fetch the `User` with the corresponding username.

Comment: That's indeed a handy solution, and I have used it in other Serializers, but in this case I cannot do it because the id to username convertion is not a simple process. I have to check another model to get the exact username, so I have chosen to do it manually in the `to_representation` method. However I cannot figure a way to do it the other way.

Comment: @BillTheKid: I don't really follow why you have to check another model? Django will check if there is indeed a `User` model with that username.

Comment: @BillTheKid: this is *not* a `SlugField`, but a `SlugRelatedField`.

Comment: Each user exists in a group. Depending on the group, the serializer will have to show extra data (`{'class': 'worker'}`). In the serialization I will have to convert the `id` into `username` and `class`. Likewise, in the deserialization I will have to convert the `username` and `class` into an `id`. Users can exist in multiple classes and may have more than one `id`.

Comment: But this is my mistake, I should have mentioned it in the post. I will add it now.

Comment: @BillTheKid: can you please edit the question with the model and the expected input/output?

Comment: This was a hasty question and not well written. I will re-write it tomorrow with more context. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: If you have time, you could check my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75372539/creating-a-custom-serializer-in-django